# Stationary covariance function three times continuously differentiable with finit support?

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing, covariance-matrix

Suppose we have an Euclidiean space $\mathbb{R}^p$ and Gaussian process with covariance function of the form $k(x_1, x_2) = k(\|x_1 - x_2\|), x_1, x_2 \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

I am looking for a covariance function from the family described above such that

- This function is three times continuously differentiable with respect to covariance function parameters and
- There exists $h$ such that $k(d) = 0$ if $d > h$ ($h$ can depend on covariance function parameters).

Do you know such a covariance function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I unfortunately don't know of a covariance function with compact support that is continuously differentiable an odd (= 3) number of times, but the [GPML book](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml) describes some piecewise polynomial CFs that are continuously differentiable an even number of times on page 88 in [chapter 4](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW4.pdf).  Note, however, that these CFs need to be parameterized over the dimensionality of your inputs.  Maybe the references quoted in the book will provide more help.

Comment: You are right, I have to look to GPML book first.

Answer (score 1):

The Kernel property, i.e. being positive definite (p.d.), is quite subtle. For example a $k$ such as above will not exist for every $p$.

The most thorough discussion of compactly supported positive definitive functions I know of can be found in Chapter 9 of "Scattered Data Approximation" by HOLGER WENDLAND. He shows (Theorem 9.2) that $k$ which is continuous, non-vanishing and p.d. for all $p$ will have $k(||x_1-x_2||)\ne 0$.

In Theorem 9.10 Wendland shows that piecewise polynomials with compact support on the unit disk which are p.d. for a certain $p$ possess $2n$ derivatives at zero and $2n + m + \lfloor \frac{p}{2}\rfloor$ derivatives at one. Chapter 9.5. contains examples for non-polynomial kernels with compact support.

By the way and only out of curiosity, what kind of application would need $C^3$?

Comment: It is not an application, but the theorem which requires such assumptions for the covariance function.